# Tableview won't reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, tableview, protocols

Sup guys? Need some help over here. I used the delegate protocol to pass some strings back from a "second view controller" to it's previous one.

My array appends the string from the method I implemented on the delegate protocol, but everytime I press "add" and come back to the first screen, the table view doesn't change. I'm not sure if the string is not being passed between views or if it's just the table view that isn't reloading.

The code is quite simple:

```
import UIKit

class EsseVaiReceber: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, PassInfoDelegate   {

    @IBOutlet var listaDeCoisasAFazer: UITableView!
    var arrayInfo : [String] = []
    var stringReceived: String = ""

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        listaDeCoisasAFazer.reloadData()
        print("SCREEN APPEARED")

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        listaDeCoisasAFazer.reloadData()
        print("LOADED SCREEN")
    }

    func passInfo(infothatwillpass: String) {
        arrayInfo.append(infothatwillpass)
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayInfo.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
        let row = indexPath.row
        let titulo = arrayInfo[row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = titulo

        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "add") {
            let view = segue.destinationViewController as! EsseVaiPassar
                view.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

and :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol PassInfoDelegate {
    func passInfo(infothatwillpass: String)

}

class EsseVaiPassar: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var campoTitulo: UITextField!
    var delegate: PassInfoDelegate?
    var textinput: String = ""


    @IBAction func botaoAdicionarCoisasAFazer(sender: AnyObject) {

        if campoTitulo == nil { return }
        textinput = campoTitulo!.text!
        print("TEXTO NO CAMPO:\(textinput)")

        if delegate == nil {
            print("DELEGATE IS NILL")
            return
    }

        delegate!.passInfo(textinput)
        print("TEXTO DO DELEGATE: \(textinput)")

        if let navigation = self.navigationController {
            navigation.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            print("INFO QUE VAI PASSAR: \(textinput)")
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the table view won't populate? Thanks advanced =)

Comment: I see you have lots of logs in the app. Can you provide the output of your excecution?

Comment: When I launch the app, the output is: "LOADED SCREEN" and "SCREEN APPEARED". When I press the add button, the output is: "TEXTO DO CAMPO: BLABLABLA", "TEXTO DO DELEGATE: BLABLABLA", "INFO QUE VAI PASSAR: BLABLABLA" and "SCREEN APPEARED".

Comment: I'm very confused about mixing delegates with tableviews.

Comment: I just tried that, won't populate or reload the table view either!

Comment: try adding a log into the  passInfo in the first controller and check if the arrayInfo.count changes when you return to the viewWillApear

Comment: Yeah it does change and increases overtime I go to "add" again. So the problem is the tableview that won't reload the data?

Comment: Is there anything in the table view? If not, you might check to make sure your `dataSource` and `delegate` are wired up.

Comment: it could be a stupid question, but is the tableView linked to the outlet in the storyboard/xib? if you manually initialize the arrayInfo with some data it loads the data?

Comment: Haha problem solved. It is actually stupid of me forgetting this little detail --' you both should answer and say something like "do never ever forget to do this again". Wasted a lot of time because of that. Really thanks to you. Sorry my n3wbness

Answer (score 1):

The tableView is using `arrayInfo` as the source for the `listaDeCoisasAFazer` tableView data (indirectly).  If you change `arrayInfo` you need to tell `listaDeCoisasAFazer` to `reloadData()`.

```
func passInfo(infothatwillpass: String) {
    arrayInfo.append(infothatwillpass)
}
```

You can/should remove the `reloadData()` from `viewWillLoad` and `viewDidLoad` as the dataSource hasn't changed so there is no need to reload the data.

**TIP**

You are checking for `nil` before the `delegate` call in the destination viewController.  Unless you are doing this for debugging purposes, you can simply call `delegate?.passInfo(textinput)`.  If delegate is nil, it will just ignore the call.